# why ReactDom.render() returns null when triggered from setState callback?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

I encountered this very weird behaviour of react and created a simple demo in below.

The behaviour is that when I do `this.renderPortal()` directly as in line 182, I can close the Dialog. But When do it from the setState callback like this:

```
return <div onClick={()=>{
  // this.renderPortal() //worker fine 
  this.setState({
    a : 1
  }, ()=>{
    this.renderPortal()
  })
}}> click me</div>
```

I cannot close it, the console will prompt `Cannot read property 'destroy' of null`.

It seemed that react thinks the Dialog rendered from setState callback stateless, Why is that?

```js
let rootDialogContainer = document.createElement("div");
document.body.appendChild(rootDialogContainer);
function createConfig(config, defaults) {
  return Object.assign(
    {},
    defaults,
    typeof config === "string" ? { content: config } : config
  );
}
class Modal extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      show: true
    };
    this.cancel = this.cancel.bind(this);

  }

  ok() {
    if (this.props.autoClose) {
      this.setState({ show: false });
    }

    const { onOk, afterClose } = this.props;
    onOk && onOk();
    afterClose();
  }

  cancel() {
    if (this.mounted && this.props.autoClose) {
      this.setState({ show: false });
    }
    const { onCancel, afterClose } = this.props;
    onCancel && onCancel();
    afterClose();
  }

  destroy() {
    this.props.forceClose();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.mounted = true
  }



  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.mounted = false
  }

  render() {
    let DialogType = this.props.dialog || Dialog;
    return (
      <DialogType
        {...this.props}
        show={this.state.show}
        onOk={this.ok}
        onCancel={this.cancel}
      />
    );
  }
}
class Dialog extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }
  renderDialogWrap(params) {
    let {      
      contentElm,
      onCancel
    } = params;




    return (
      <div className={"dialog"}>
        <div style={{}} className={"inner-dialog"}>     
          {contentElm}
          <div className="button" onClick={onCancel}>
            cancel
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  renderPortal() {
    return <Modal />;
  }
  render() {
    let props = this.props;
    let {
      show,
      className,
      title,
      content,
      onCancel = () => {},
      onOk = () => {},           
      children,
      renderAsHiddenIfNotShow = false,
    } = props;
    return ReactDOM.createPortal(
      <div
        style={{ display: show ? "" : "none" }}
     
      >
        {this.renderDialogWrap({
          onCancel,
          contentElm: children,          
          show,
          renderAsHiddenIfNotShow
        })}
      </div>,
      document.body
    ); 
  }
}
Dialog.show = function(params) {
  const config = createConfig(params, {
    show: true,
    autoClose: true,    
    onOk: () => {},
    onCancel: () => {}
  });

  config.content = config.content || config.desc;

  let container = rootDialogContainer


  if (config.id) {
   
    let containerId = `wrapper`
    container = document.getElementById(containerId)
    if (!container) {
      container = document.createElement('div')
      container.setAttribute('id', containerId)
      document.body.appendChild(container)
    }
  }

  config.forceClose = function(){
    ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(container);
  };

  config.afterClose = function() {
    config.autoClose && config.forceClose();
  };

  return ReactDOM.render(this.buildModal(config), container);;
};
class Wrapper extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
  }
  renderPortal(){
    const destroy = () => {
      this.myDialog.destroy();
    };

    this.myDialog = Dialog.show({
      onOk: ()=>{},
      onCancel: destroy,
      onClose: destroy,
      autoClose: false,
      content:  <div>
        <p>Test</p>
      </div>
    });  
  }
  render(){
    return <div onClick={()=>{
      // this.renderPortal() //worker fine 
      this.setState({
        a : 1
      }, ()=>{
        this.renderPortal()
      })
    }}> click me</div>
  }
}
Dialog.buildModal = function(config) {
  return <Modal {...config} />;
};

function App() {

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Wrapper />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```css
.dialog{
    HEIGHT: 50px;
    background: white;
    border:1px solid gray;
    top: 20px;
    width: 500px;
    position: absolute;

}
.inner-dialog{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.button{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    border:1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: *"...created a simple demo here..."* Please ensure the question has **all** the necessary code **in the question**. (This question doesn't, it doesn't even have the `ReactDom` [sic] call.) You can do that by using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The demo link is actually attached already if look closely.

Comment: link != in the question

Comment: @ChrisG what does it mean?

Comment: It means that your link won't be active in some [near] future and everyone who visit your OP won't know what are you referencing to. So, create a [SO snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) and you're good to go.

Comment: @Blake Create a [mcve].

Comment: @ChrisG created an example, included babel and necessary react libraries, simply won't work, and prompted some ununderstandable error. Why can't people just click on the link i provided?? is it that hard?

Comment: @DavidLemon I called it from setstate callback, why it is an antipattern?

Comment: It is not an anti-pattern, if what u really want is stateless dialogs in order for example to limit re-rendering and improve performance. Pure react approach would be to have a state variable for each dialog.

Answer (score -1):

The reason is very simple, while your dialog in itself is stateless, it is rendered while rendering a stateful component and thus `ReactDom.render` will deem it at stateful.

A simple hack to bypass the issue is to replace:

```
this.setState({
    a : 1
  }, ()=>{
    this.renderPortal()
  })
})
```

with

```
this.setState({
    a : 1
  }, ()=>{
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.renderPortal()
    }, 1)
  })
```

This way your component is considered as stateless.

Full code:

```js
let rootDialogContainer = document.createElement("div");
document.body.appendChild(rootDialogContainer);
function createConfig(config, defaults) {
  return Object.assign(
    {},
    defaults,
    typeof config === "string" ? { content: config } : config
  );
}
class Modal extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      show: true
    };
    this.cancel = this.cancel.bind(this);

  }

  ok() {
    if (this.props.autoClose) {
      this.setState({ show: false });
    }

    const { onOk, afterClose } = this.props;
    onOk && onOk();
    afterClose();
  }

  cancel() {
    if (this.mounted && this.props.autoClose) {
      this.setState({ show: false });
    }
    const { onCancel, afterClose } = this.props;
    onCancel && onCancel();
    afterClose();
  }

  destroy() {
    this.props.forceClose();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.mounted = true
  }



  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.mounted = false
  }

  render() {
    let DialogType = this.props.dialog || Dialog;
    return (
      <DialogType
        {...this.props}
        show={this.state.show}
        onOk={this.ok}
        onCancel={this.cancel}
      />
    );
  }
}
class Dialog extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }
  renderDialogWrap(params) {
    let {      
      contentElm,
      onCancel
    } = params;




    return (
      <div className={"dialog"}>
        <div style={{}} className={"inner-dialog"}>     
          {contentElm}
          <div className="button" onClick={onCancel}>
            cancel
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  renderPortal() {
    return <Modal />;
  }
  render() {
    let props = this.props;
    let {
      show,
      className,
      title,
      content,
      onCancel = () => {},
      onOk = () => {},           
      children,
      renderAsHiddenIfNotShow = false,
    } = props;
    return ReactDOM.createPortal(
      <div
        style={{ display: show ? "" : "none" }}
     
      >
        {this.renderDialogWrap({
          onCancel,
          contentElm: children,          
          show,
          renderAsHiddenIfNotShow
        })}
      </div>,
      document.body
    ); 
  }
}
Dialog.show = function(params) {
  const config = createConfig(params, {
    show: true,
    autoClose: true,    
    onOk: () => {},
    onCancel: () => {}
  });

  config.content = config.content || config.desc;

  let container = rootDialogContainer


  if (config.id) {
   
    let containerId = `wrapper`
    container = document.getElementById(containerId)
    if (!container) {
      container = document.createElement('div')
      container.setAttribute('id', containerId)
      document.body.appendChild(container)
    }
  }

  config.forceClose = function(){
    ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(container);
  };

  config.afterClose = function() {
    config.autoClose && config.forceClose();
  };

  return ReactDOM.render(this.buildModal(config), container);;
};
class Wrapper extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
  }
  renderPortal(){
    const destroy = () => {
      this.myDialog.destroy();
    };

    this.myDialog = Dialog.show({
      onOk: ()=>{},
      onCancel: destroy,
      onClose: destroy,
      autoClose: false,
      content:  <div>
        <p>Test</p>
      </div>
    });  
  }
  render(){
    return <div onClick={()=>{
      // this.renderPortal() //worker fine 
      this.setState({
        a : 1
      }, ()=>{
        setTimeout(() => this.renderPortal(), 1)
      })
    }}> click me</div>
  }
}
Dialog.buildModal = function(config) {
  return <Modal {...config} />;
};

function App() {

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Wrapper />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```css
.dialog{
    HEIGHT: 500px;
    background: white;
    border:1px solid gray;
    top: 20px;
    width: 500px;
    position: absolute;

}
.inner-dialog{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.button{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    border:1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

[Updated demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xzdkw2)

Comment: Just don't understand Why the code you provide makes the dialog stateful? And why it is not considered stateful if called in setstate callback?

Comment: When you call a setState: React will first apply change to state, propagate to states (in case there is other changes induced by this state change), apply the callback, propagate again, rerender the component, verify if the state has change and restart the whole process if it is the case (we try to limit this cases by not changing the state in the callbacks, thus the anti pattern mentioned above). Any component created during this process will be considered as stateful.

Comment: what you are saying is that the dialog called from the setstate callback makes it a stateful component?? But isn't is the opposite way? React thinks called from the setstate callback is stateless, that's why ReactDom.render() returns null and makes the dialog not closable.

Comment: And why change state in setState callback is anti-pattern? This answer seemed to recommend such way of using setState.